# Set request content to test in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-3.4

I have to set a test to check the user registragion with an API , but I'm not sure how to set the content, its has to had a header with the `token named` x-auth-token`and the body with a`form-data` param named data that contains  json-string

```
 public function testUserRegister(){
    $client = static::createClient();
    $server = array('x-auth-token' => '...');
    $client->request(Request::METHOD_POST, self::$uri, [], [], $server);
    $response = $client->getResponse();

    self::assertEquals( Response::HTTP_CREATED, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

When I check on the debug ther is no `x-auth-token` on the headers

Comment: i dont understand your code seem good !! do you have any error ?

Comment: the parameters are not sent,  I get a 400 error because the token it's not arriving

Comment: which api are you using ?

Comment: Its an api developed for me, it works correct but I can't set te request for the test

Answer (score -1):

Use third parameter of `$client->request` method to pass your data.

If you want to send payload as form data with JSON, you need to do something like this:

```
$client->request(..., ..., ['data' => json_encode(...)], ...);
```

Keep in mind that you maybe need to set correct `Content-Type` in header (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).